# Latex template for report studies

Tags: templates, report

Please i want a latex template for the report of my final project studies.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I fear, this 'request' will be declined

Comment: How about just using `\documentclass{report}`, its often much easier to deal with a standard document class. Otherwise goggle may provide you with many template hosting repositories.

Comment: Do some research online to find out how a Latex document is constructed and look through a few exemplars to get familiar with the basic **packages** used to define the document and the **commands** used to organise text, figures and tables. **THEN**, come back when you get stuck with the code you have been using so that someone can provide you with better advice. Learning by doing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you wish:

https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/national-school-of-engineers-of-sfax-enis-report/xjrnfvzfxqrn#.VzBuF0JcFpg

or you can search an other on

https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/

Comment: It's worrying that the original poster (OP) didn't take the time to do some basic research and find exactly the same templates as suggested by @TomSolid. I also wonder how useful the template will be given the lack of enthusiam to get informed about using Latex. Without this, a template is, to paraphrase Ed Murrow, 'just wires and lights in a box'.

Comment: A starter usually cannot judge the quality of something. For example any car seller would tell me that his car is working well and is at a good prize, and would need to believe him because i don't have the needed experience. Or i get some help by  someone who is familiar with cars (how would i know that he is?). Or in other words, you need to do some research before starting a new project.

Comment: By the way, that template, as so many others, has a few errors in it.